# Oracle ODBC Error 12170 - Accessing over Internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp, database, odbc

I have Oracle 8i on Windows XP 32 connected to a router. I have installed Oracle client v10 (64 bit) on Windows 7  64 laptop connected to the same router. I am able to make & successfully test ODBC connection from my laptop to Oracle 8i on LAN.

However the moment I change the IP address to the public IP of router (My ISP assigns me a Public IP) in TNSNAMES.ORA on the client & try to access it over the Internet (Internet from another mobile 3G ISP) the connection fails with oracle - ORA-12170 TNS Timeout.

I have checked that

1. The firewalls on both XP & Windows 7 are OFF including the Firewall service
2. Port forwarding in router is tested successfully for both ports 1521 & 2481 where listener is running on XP (yougetsignal.com)
3. I temporarily enabled all ports from 1 to 6000 in router assuming that there might be some other port I am missing and is applicable
4. Put XP machine on DMZ in router
5. PATH includes Oracle home and I have also set TNS_LANG & TNS_ADMIN variables

However the ODBC fails over the internet.
Are there any other considerations, Oracle services or anything else that I am missing? At this juncture it’s hard to point out if this is networking or oracle configuration issue.

**Update**

It appears to me that ODBC is actually making a connection over the internet on port 1521, but somehow returning timeout. This is what reflects in the listener.log on the server.

`10-SEP-2017 21:20:08 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TESTDB)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe)(HOST=VAIO)(USER=xxxxx))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=x.x.x.x)(PORT=5865)) * establish * TESTDB *` 0

Thanks